# ¿Qué significa (*variable) en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

He visto varias programadores que usan el * antes de una variable, por ejemplo:

```
req.add_header('Range', 'bytes={}-{}'.format(*rango))
```

¿Qué significa lo anteriormente descrito, con un solo * o con dos **?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Con *, le dices a Python que quieres pasar cada ítem de la lista, tupla o cualquier otra sequencia como argumentos de la función. Por ejemplo:

```
print(*(1,2,3))
```

es equivalente a:

```
print(1,2,3)
```

---

** Es más complejo, con esto le dices que quieres pasar cada key:value de un diccionario a la función. Por ejemplo:

```
print(**{'separator':'-', 'end':'-'})
```

Es equivalente a:

```
print(separator='-', end='-')
```

Mas allá de que funcionen o no los códigos antes dichos, eso es lo que hace * y ** en Python.

---

**Actualización**

Cuando se colocan como argumentos en funciones, tienen otro significado:
Por ejemplo en `def func(hola, *args)`, estás diciendo que la función tiene un primer argumento obligatorio (hola), pero acepta opcionalmente una cantidad infinita de otros argumentos, los cuales se guardan en la variable que aclares luego del *, en este caso `args`, en forma de tupla.
Por ejemplo, en la llamada `func(1,2,3)`, args valdrá `(2,3)`.

Por otro lado, al hacer lo mismo con ** hace que la función acepte infinitos argumentos, pero hay que aclarar primero el nombre del argumento. Por ejemplo `def func(hola, **kargs)`. Si llamas a esta función asi `func(0, key=1)` va a funcionar, pero no funcionará `func(0, 1)`.
Lo que encontrarás dentro de kargs, será un diccionario con los argumentos ingresados. En el caso del ejemplo, sería `{'key':1}`.

Finalmente, puedes combinar ambos casos para que la función acepte tanto argumentos infinitos como argumentos del tipo de ** asi: `def func(hola, *args, **kargs)`. Ahora es posible llamar a la funcion de, por ejemplo, esta manera: `func(1,2,3, key='hola mundo')`. En este caso, args valdrá `(2,3)` y kargs `{'key':'hola mundo'}`

Comment: Para conocerlo por su nombre, es: [Unpacking Operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/)

Comment: Hice una actualización a la respuesta con algo de información extra (: