# ¿Como borrar mas de un registro de una treeview en Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7

Estoy intentando borrar mas de un registro de la tablar pero me da este error :**_tkinter.TclError: Item I003 I002 not found**. ¿Algo que se pueda hacer?

```
tree = ttk.Treeview(ventana, columns = 2)
tree.column("#0", width = "150")
tree.column("#1", width = "140")
tree.place(x = 670, y = 210, width = "300", height = "200")

btnBorrar = Button(tree, text = "Borrar", bg = "light blue", command=lambda:borrar_productos())
btnBorrar.config(font = ("Roboto", 10))
btnBorrar.config(bd = 2, relief = "groove", borderwidth = 3, cursor = "hand2")
btnBorrar.place(x = 150, y = 180, width = "152", height = "22")

def borrar_productos():
        global tree
        tree.delete(tree.get_children())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Explicación

El comando `tree.get_children()` devuelve una tupla que contiene el id de todos los items del Treeview.
En el método `delete` cada argumento es la id de un item a eliminar.

Al ejecutar `tree.delete(tree.get_children())`, estás pasandole un solo argumento (una tupla) y Tkinter cree que se trata de un solo item. Y por alguna razón interna que desconozco, procesa esa tupla de una forma especial.
En tu escenario particular, es el equivalente a ejecutar `tree.delete(('I003', 'I002'))`.

#### Solución 1

Puedes pasarle todos los items de una en forma de argumentos usando el [unpacking](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/428956/qu%c3%a9-significa-variable-en-python/428961#428961):

```
tree.delete(*tree.get_children())
```

#### Solución 2

Puedes eliminar los items uno a uno usando un bucle for que recorra la tupla devuelta por `tree.get_children()` y pasando cada id a `tree.delete`:

```
for item in tree.get_children():
    tree.delete(item)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ya pude solucionarlo.