# Para que sirve *args en una funcion de python?

Tags: python

al momento de hacer funciones, hay veces en las que ponen como parámetro (*args) no entiendo que es lo que hace, busco en foros pero no logro entender, alguien me puede explicar por favor

Comment: No necesitas buscar en foros. En la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html) en la sección ***argument*** te lo explica. Saludos

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jj_NKNDC7Aw

Comment: Hace tiempo, respondí que hace *args en otra pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/428956/qu%c3%a9-significa-variable-en-python/428961#428961 (lo que buscas se explica en la actualización)