# Como Edito una linea de un archivo de textp en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Necesito agregar al archivo una etiqueta Ejemplo:

```
archivo.txt sin editar:
google.com
facebook.com
```

quisiera agregarle algo asi:

```
archivo.txt editado:
Link usado google.com
facebook.com
```

este es mi codigo:

```
i=0
while i !=10:    
    linea=0
    f = open("todos_los_links.txt", "r") 
    link = f.readlines()[linea]
    file = open("ultimo_link_enviado.txt", "w")
    for lineal in linea:
        file.write("Link usado".join("link")+"\n")
        
    file.close()
    linea+=1
    i+=1
```

**el problema es que me borra el documento entero y solo me deja una linea y quiero que me edite solo una linea**

Comment: No puedes cambiar una sola línea. Debes leer el fichero entero y volver a escribirlo entero, cambiando en el proceso las líneas que te interesen.

Comment: @abulafia en realidad, para este caso especifico, se puede abrir el archivo en modo "a", ir al inicio de la linea a modificar y agregar el texto. Lo que parece ser imposible es borrar caracteres en un fichero. Además, el OP precisamente hace eso, reescribir el archivo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes lograr tu objetivo de este modo:

#### Código

```
with open("todos_los_links.txt") as src, open("ultimo_link_enviado.txt", "w") as dest:
    for index, line in enumerate(src, start=1):
        dest.write(("Link Usado " + line) if(index == 2) else line)
```

#### Explicación

```
with open("todos_los_links.txt") as src, open("ultimo_link_enviado.txt", "w") as dest:
```

El with se encarga de, en caso de los archivos, cerrarlos automáticamente cuando el bloque de código que encierran termina de ejecutarse.

```
for index, line in enumerate(src, start=1)
```

Iteramos sobre cada linea del archivo original. Enumeramos cada linea comenzando por 1 usando la función enumerate. En cada iteración recibiremos una tupla del estilo `(numero de linea, linea)`, la cual podemos aplicarle el [unpacking](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/428956/qu%c3%a9-significa-variable-en-python/428961#428961) para obtener ambos items por separado en variables separadas.

```
dest.write(("Link Usado " + line) if(index == 2) else line)
```

Escribimos la linea en el nuevo archivo. Si la linea es la 2, agregamos la cadena `"link usado "` al principio de la linea a escribir. Puedes cambiar ese 2 por el numero de linea que necesites.

#### Produce

Al abrir el archivo aparece lo siguiente:

```
google.com
Link Usado facebook.com
```