# sumar componentes de tipo lista y agregar a una nueva en Python

Tags: python

estoy intentando multiplicar dos valores de una componentes de tipo lista, y que cada multiplicacion se agregue a una nueva lista. pero no he logrado hacerlo.

Ejemplo:

```
lista=[[1000,3], [200,40]]
```

requiero hacer que el valor de las listas internas se multiplique y se agregue a una nueva lista quedando algo asi:

```
NuevaLista = [3000,8000]
```

He intentado con este ciclo for pero sin mucho avence

```
list=[[1000,3], [200,40]]
nuevaLista=[]
for k in range(len(list)):
    mult=1
    for x in range(len(list[k])):
        mult=mult*list[k][x]
        print(mult)
nuevaLista.append([mult])
print(nuevaLista)
```

los resultados los imprime de esta forma
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando comprensión de listas:

```
lista=[[1000,3], [200,40]]
prod = [x[0] * x[1] for x in lista]
print(prod)
```

produce:

```
[3000, 8000]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: O usando el [unpacking](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/428956/qu%c3%a9-significa-variable-en-python/428961#428961) y asumiendo que todas las sublistas tendrán siempre dos elementos: `x0*x1 for x0, x1 in lista`

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciono perfecto.