# Como interpretar la informacion de una libreria de Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, importación, modulos

Esta es la primera vez que estoy leyendo la documentación de un modulo que importe para Python. Es un modulo para convertir segundos a minutos (lo estoy leyendo desde la consola cmd con la función help(-nombre del modulo-)).
El caso es que soy nuevo en el mundo de la programación y no entiendo bien como interpretar la información que me da la terminal.
**Mi principal duda** es que al principio me dice **-Secs(time,** ****options**)-. Entiendo que -Secs- es el nombre de la función para convertir segundos a minutos y -time- es el parámetro para colocar el tiempo que quiero convertir (por ejemplo 60 segundos). **Mi duda viene con el parámetro** -****options**-. Entiendo que hace referencia a las opciones que tengo para manipular el tiempo que coloque en el primer parámetro, **lo que no entiendo es cuales son esas opciones y como colocarlas.**
Me explico. Abajo dice:

```
    Parameters
 |     ` ----------
 |      time
 |          The time which will be converted.
 |
 |  pluralize(self, time, abs_time, time_type, name: str)
 |      Pluralize the output if time is greater than 1.`
```

ENTIENDO QUE ESTA PARTE HACE REFERENCIA AL PARAMETRO -time- pero **no entiendo a que hace referencia cuando dice** - **pluralize(self, time, abs_time, time_type, name: str) Pluralize the output if time is greater than 1**.-. No entiendo si -self-, -time-, -abs_time-, -time_type- y -name: str- se agregar al primer parámetro - time- o a que hace referencia

POR OTRO LADO MAS ABAJO DICE:

```
Parameters
 |      ----------
 |      time
 |          The time which will be pluralized.
 |      abs_time
 |          The absolute time.
 |      time_type
 |          The time type (mins, hrs, etc.).
 |      name
 |          The time name (minute, hour, etc.)
```

.

**Acá viene mi mayor duda**. **No entiendo si los parámetros -time-, -abs_time-, -time_type- y -name- son para colocar en el segundo parametro de -Secs(time, ES DECIR ACA!!)- o para que son.**
En caso de que puedan colocarse como segundo parámetro de la funcion Secs, no se como colocarlos para que funcionen

**En resumidas cuentas, entiendo que puedo invocar la funcion Secs(-y colocar dentro de este parámetro el tiempo que quiero convertir, por ejemplo 60 segundos-), lo principal que no me queda claro es como aplicar los parametros de **options (time-, -abs_time-, -time_type- y -name)**

Dejo una captura de pantalla de la informacion de la consola por si sirve de mayor utilidad:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: La primera duda que tienes la respondo aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/428956/qu%c3%a9-significa-variable-en-python/428961#428961

Comment: Sobre tu segunda duda, parece que la documentación obtenida con help no indica que keyword args (que son los argumentos estilo hola='mundo') recibe. Esos asteriscos indican que una cantidad infinita de keyword args se guarda en la variable options internamente en la función en forma de diccionario.

Comment: Pluralize es un método y convert es otro diferente, no los confundas. Aun así **especulo** que internamente los keyword args que pases a Secs se pasan a pluralize. Sin embargo, es especulación, si pasases el link al modulo podría darte respuestas más exactas.

Comment: @DanteS. Dale bro, ahora te paso el link
https://pypi.org/project/seconds/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La verdad, me parece una documentación un poco vaga la que ofrecen en ese modulo.

#### Que hace **

Esto no es particular de este modulo. Es una caracteristica de Python.

La funcionalidad del `**` en las funciones la explico en esta respuesta: [¿Qué significa (*variable) en Python?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/428956/qu%c3%a9-significa-variable-en-python/428961#428961)

Citaré la parte relevante por si el link se cae:

> Por otro lado, al hacer lo mismo con ** hace que la función acepte
> infinitos argumentos, pero hay que aclarar primero el nombre del
> argumento. Por ejemplo `def func(hola, **kargs)`. Si llamas a esta
> función asi `func(0, key=1)` va a funcionar, pero no funcionará
> `func(0, 1)`. Lo que encontrarás dentro de kargs, será un diccionario
> con los argumentos ingresados. En el caso del ejemplo, sería
> `{'key':1}`.

#### Que keyword args acepta Secs

Bueno, como podrás ver, `**options` acepta infinitos argumentos cuyos nombres pueden ser cualquiera. Por diversos motivos puede suceder un error si se pasan keyword args de más (un error creado por el propio modulo, que internamente estos argumentos sean pasados a una función que solo acepta ciertos keyword args, etc).

Como en la documentación de `help` no se indica que keyboard args acepta options, no nos queda de otra que revisar el código fuente de Secs:

```
class Secs:
    """
    Seconds class
    """

    # Default options
    abbrev = False

    def __new__(cls, time, **options):
        """
        Set the time to convert and the output options.
        ...
        Parameters
        ----------
        time
            The time that will be converted.
        options
            The options that control the output.
        Raises
        ------
        TypeError
            if time isn't a String or an Integer.
        """

        if not isinstance(time, (str, int)): #or not isinstance(time, int):
            raise TypeError(f"time must be a String or an Integer in \"{inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name}\".")
        else:
            # Get options
            if "abbrev" in options:
                # Raise error if abbrev isn't a Boolean.
                if not isinstance(options["abbrev"], bool):
                    raise TypeError(
                        "abbrev must be a Boolean in options parameter in options parameter in \"{inspect.currentframe)(.f_code.co_name)}\".")
                else:
                    cls.abbrev = options["abbrev"]
            return cls.convert(cls, time)
```

Y analizandolo, nos damos cuenta que el unico keyword arg usado realmente es un booleano llamado `abbrev`. Puedes pasarle cualquier otra cosa sin efectos negativos, pero el código no lo usaría.

#### En que afecta el argumento abbrev

Esto no está documentado oficialmente, pero en un ejemplo:

```
# Lets import Secs class from Seconds Package
from seconds import Secs

# Lets pass 5 minutes to seconds and seconds to 10 minutes
Secs("5m") # => 300
Secs(600)  # => 10 minutes
# But we want to abbreviate our minutes so we
# will pass the abbrev parameter to options
Secs(600, abbrev=True) # => 10m

# Lets pass 6 months to seconds and then pass 1 year to seconds
Secs("6mo") # => 110451600
Secs("1y")  # => 220903200
```

Parece que escribe una forma abreviada. Es decir, minutes lo transforma en m, hour en h, etc.

Sin embargo, con más pruebas, parece que Secs devuelve la versión abreviada por default y esto se puede deshabilitar con abbrev=True, contradiciendo los comentarios en el ejemplo en el repositorio.

Es más, las pruebas y los analisis al código fuente me indicaron que el valor default de abbrev es cambiado cada vez que llamas a Secs.

Ejemplo:

```
from seconds import Secs

# abbrev = False (devuelve abreviado)
print(Secs(3600))

# abbrev = True (devuelve sin abreviar)
print(Secs(3600, abbrev=True))

# abbrev = True (devuelve sin abreviar)
print(Secs(3600))
```

Produce:

```
1h
1 hour
1 hour
```

#### Documentación no oficial basada en este analisis

Secs acepta un argumento opcional llamado abbrev que:

- Su valor default se establece al valor que le pases cada vez que llames a Secs (confuso, verdad?)
- Si es True, devuelve la versión sin abreviar
- Si es False, devuelve la versión abreviada

Mi opinión, este modulo no está bien hecho, es confuso y es seguro que el autor no lo diseñó como pensaba ni hizo las pruebas adecuadas para asegurarse de que funcione bien. Te recomiendo recurrir a otro modulo, o hacer el tuyo propio.

#### Que es self

Debido a una duda que presentas en los comentarios, me dedicaré a explicar que es self.

Imagina que tenemos el siguiente código:

```
class Vehiculo:
    def __init__(self, tipo):
        self.tipo = tipo

    def print(self, ruedas):
        print(f"El vehiculo {self.tipo}' tiene {ruedas} ruedas")

auto = Vehiculo("auto")
auto.print(4)
```

Cuando esta linea se ejecuta `auto.print(4)` internamente se hace `Vehiculo.print(auto, 4)`. Ese es el primer argumento que recibe la función print. Por convenio, ese argumento es llamado `self`.

Normalmente, este proceso es automático, por lo que no suele ser necesario pasar el argumento self.

Cuando llamas a una clase como sucede en esta linea: `Vehiculo("auto")`, lo **normal** es que se devuelva un objeto especial relacionado con la clase Vehiculo. Ese objeto se llama `instancia`. Y la acción de crear una instancia, se llama `instanciar`.

Cuando ejecutas Vehiculo.print() te están faltando dos argumentos, self, que en este caso **no** se pasa automaticamente (ese argumento se agrega automaticamente solo cuando el método (función dentro de una clase) es llamado desde una instancia) y ruedas.

#### Como influye esto en el módulo

En este caso, debido a como está hecho un método especial llamado `__new__`, resulta imposible (sin alterar el código original) de instanciar a Secs. Intentar instanciar a Secs resultará en obtener un entero o una cadena.

Parece que el uso de convert y pluralize es de proposito interno. Y en el caso particular de este módulo, cada vez que estos métodos son llamados, self resulta ser Secs (pero la clase, no la instancia).

Aun así, si insistes en usarlos puedes hacerlo así:

```
Secs.convert(Secs, [el tiempo a convertir])
```

#### El error NameError

El error NameError ocurre cuando recurres a una variable, pero Python no la encuentra por ningún lado.

Ejemplo:

```
def a():
    def b():
        c()

    b()

a()
```

En este caso, cuando la función b se ejecuta, busca la variable c dentro de b, luego dentro de a, luego fuera de toda función. Y como no la encuentra, ocurre el siguiente error:

```
NameError: name 'c' is not defined
```

Eso es lo que te pasó con self.

Comment: La ultima duda es que pasa entonces con los parámetros time (este lo entiendo), -abs_time-, -time_type- y -name- que figuran mas abajo?

-Secs- acepta solamente el argumento abbrev?

Comment: @khuranes Esos argumentos pertenecen al método pluralize. Secs acepta el argumento time y un keyword arg abbrev. Cualquier otro keyword arg que le pases no hará nada.

Comment: Todas tus explicaciones me ayudaron realmente mucho, demuestra que además de saber mucho del tema, tenes muy buena predisposición para ayudar a los novatos y eso me llena de ganas de seguir aprendiendo jaja. 
Ya casi soy capaz de interpretar toda la informacion que me da la consola, tengo una ultima duda:

Comment: si yo coloco este script -print(Secs.convert())- la consola de python me lanza el siguiente error:  missing 2 required positional arguments: 'self' and 'time'.
Entiendo que el error se debe a que tengo que colocar los 2 argumentos del metodo -self y time(el tiempo que quiero convertir), Mi duda es que cuando coloco -self- y el numero que quiero convertir, me sale -name "self" is not definder
-

Comment: Lo mismo me sucede con el método pluralice. Le coloco el parámetro "self" y todos los demás parámetros y me devuelve el error "name self is not defined"
Que tengo que colocar en vez de "self para que me ejecute el metodo?"

Comment: Al parametro "self" lo tengo que cambiar por alguna otra palabra(viendo que no me lo acepta) o cual es el error)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tus palabras c: Me gusta ayudar y explicar nwn. Por cierto, edité la respuesta explicando que es self, como influye en el modulo y el error NameError.

Comment: Muchas gracias por toda la ayuda hermano, sigo con muchas dudas pero se me aclaro un poco el panorama jaja. Te hago la ultima pregunta. Ademas de pypi, que otro lugar me recomendas para buscar librerias para python?

Comment: Sinceramente, no conozco ningún otro. De nada c: