# Problema para ejecutar una libreria creada por mi mismo

Tags: python, poo, funciones, parametros, modulos

A modo de practica cree un pequeño modulo llamado Herramientas, compuesto por una serie de metodos

```
class Herramientas:
    def __init__(self, listaNumeros):
        self.lista = listaNumeros

# FACTORIAL

    def factorial(self):
        for i in self.lista:
            self.__factorial(i)

    def __factorial(self, numero):
        from math import factorial
        factorial = factorial(numero)
        print(f"el factorial de {numero} es {factorial}")


# NUMEROS PRIMOS


    def primoLista(self):
        for i in self.lista:
            self.__primo(i)

    def __primo(self, n):
        contador = 0
        for i in range(1, n+1):
            if n % i == 0:
                contador += 1
        if contador == 2:
            print(f"{n} es primo")
            return True
        else:
            print(f"{n} no es primo")
            return False

# MODALES

    def numerosRepetidos(self):
        self.__numerosRepetidos(self.lista)

    def __numerosRepetidos(self, listaRepetidos):
        from statistics import mode
        print(
            f"el numero que mas se repite es el {mode(listaRepetidos)} y se repite {listaRepetidos.count(mode(listaRepetidos))} veces")
```

Probando los diferentes metodos dentro del archivo original donde cree la clase, me funcionan correctamente. El problema viene cuando importo el modulo a un nuevo archivo.py

el archivo donde cree la clase, se llama **ejerciciosFunciones.py** y el nuevo archivo donde importo el modulo se llama **importancionDeModulos.py**

en el nuevo archivo .py coloco el siguiente script: **from ejerciciosFunciones import Herramientas**. Lo hago de esta manera porque dentro del archivo ejerciciosFunciones.py tengo otras clases echas pero solamente me interesaba importar la clase Herramientas

En el nuevo archivo.py, luego de importar el modulo Herramientas, cuando intento utilizar alguno de los metodos del modulo, la consola me lanza un error

En este ejemplo, intento ejecutar la funcion factorial:

```
from ejerciciosFunciones import Herramientas

lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

Herramientas(lista)
Herramientas.factorial()
```

Y el error que me tira la consola es el siguiente:

**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Khuranes\Desktop\Data Science Sublime\Henry\Henry-Python-Prep\07 - Classes & OOP\importancionDeModulos.py", line 6, in 
Herramientas.factorial()

TypeError: Herramientas.factorial() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
PS C:\Users\Khuranes\Desktop\Data Science Sublime\Henry>**

Mi principal duda es que a partir del error puedo entender que a la Herramientas.factorial() le falta un argumento "self". El problema es que no entiendo que parametro colocar para que me ejecute la funcion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un error de concepto sobre como funcionan las clases en Python.
Esto ya me dediqué a explicarlo en [otra respuesta que te dí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/527418/158880), pero aun así lo volveré a explicar. Te recomiendo releer la sección "que es self" para entender aun mejor como funciona.

---

#### Explicación

La forma correcta sería:

```
from ejerciciosFunciones import Herramientas

lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

herramientas = Herramientas(lista)
herramientas.factorial()
```

A continuación explicaré lo que hace linea por linea:

```
herramientas = Herramientas(lista)
```

Cuando pones parentesis a la derecha de una clase, la invocas. Al invocar la clase se hacen algunas cosas internas en las que no nos centraremos. Pero en algún momento se llama a un método especial llamado `__init__`. Lo que termina por devolver el invocar una clase *generalmente*  es un objeto especial relacionado con dicha clase, en este caso de la clase Herramientas. Ese objeto especial se llama instancia, y la acción de crear una instancia se llama instanciar.

El obtener una instancia llamando a una clase puede no ser posible (vease la respuesta mencionada al principio para ver un caso en el que no se puede instanciar una clase normalmente).

En el código de más arriba, la instancia se guarda en una variable llamada `herramientas` (notese que está en minuscula, Python es case-sensitive).

```
herramientas.factorial()
```

Cuando ejecutas esta linea, internamente se hace una llamada a `Herramientas.factorial(herramientas)`. Ese primer argumento, por convenio es llamado `self`. Siempre que llames un método de Herramientas desde una de sus instancias, `self` se pasa automáticamente como primer argumento, por lo que no hace falta que lo pases explícitamente.

#### Bonus

El llamar a un método y que este imprima el resultado en pantalla no siempre es un comportamiento deseado. Si quieres flexibilizar tus métodos de clase, te recomiendo retornar el valor obtenido por tu función y luego imprimir el resultado en consola.

Comment: Claro ahora entiendo. Tenia que instanciar la clase Herramientas. Se como hacerlo pero, al ser la primera vez que utilizaba la importación de un modulo creado por mi mismo, pensé que el procedimiento era otro. Ahora me queda claro!