# Eliminar elemento creado en una clase con listas Python

Tags: python, poo

Estaba desarrollando un ejercicio de clase que permite gestionar canciones. Con lo que llevo quería saber como podría eliminar una canción añadida a la lista, lo intenté con del, pero al volver a mostrar la opción 4 me sale AttributeError.

Mi avance es el siguiente, y estuve trabajando en eliminarCancion(). Eliminé un poco de código para publicar. Gracias

lista = []

class Cancion:

```
def __init__(self, titulo, interprete, duracion, estilo):

    self.titulo = titulo
    self.interprete = interprete
    self.duracion = duracion
    self.estilo = estilo

def resumen(self):

    print(f'\n Canción: {self.titulo}, Intérprete: {self.interprete}')

def __str__(self):

    cadena = f'\n Título: {self.titulo}\n'
    cadena = cadena + f' Intérprete: {self.interprete}\n'
    cadena = cadena + f' Duración: {self.duracion}\n'
    cadena = cadena + f' Estilo de música: {self.estilo}'
    return cadena
```

def listarEstilo():

```
estilo = input('Ingrese el estilo de la canción: ')
print(f'\n Canciones con el estilo {estilo}:\n')
for tema in lista:
    if tema.estilo == estilo:
        print(f' {tema.titulo}, duración: {tema.duracion}')
```

def eliminarCancion():

```
eliminar = input('Ingrese el título de la canción: ')
for tema in lista:
    if tema.titulo == eliminar:
        print(f'\n La canción {tema.titulo} ha sido borrada.')
        del tema.titulo
        del tema.interprete
        del tema.duracion
        del tema.estilo
```

def menu():

```
print('\n Gestión MP3')
opcion = 0
while opcion != 9:
    print('\n1) Añadir una nueva canción')
    print('2) Listar canciones de un intérprete')
    print('3) Listar canciones de un estilo')
    print('4) Listar todas las canciones')
    print('5) Eliminar una canción')
    print('9) Salir del programa\n')
    opcion = int(input('Ingrese una opcion: '))

    if opcion == 1:
        a = input('Ingrese el título de la canción: ')
        b = input('Ingrese el intérprete de la canción: ')
        c = input('Ingrese la duración de la canción: ')
        d = input('Ingrese el estilo de la canción: ')
        tema = Cancion(a,b,c,d)
        lista.append(tema)
        print(tema)

    elif opcion == 2:
        listarInterprete()

    elif opcion == 3:
        listarEstilo()

    elif opcion == 4:
        for tema in lista:
            tema.resumen()

    elif opcion == 5:
        eliminarCancion()

    elif opcion == 9:
        print('\n Gracias por usar el programa')
```

menu()

Answer (score 0):

Puedes recorrer la lista con un bucle for hasta obtener el índice de la canción cuyo titulo coincide y usar `del lista[indice]` para borrarla. Esta sintaxis hace que se elimine un ítem con el índice indice de la lista.

Para este objetivo usaremos la función [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/functions.html#enumerate). Es un poco más complejo que eso, pero imagina que devuelve una lista del estilo `[(0, item0), (1, item1), ...]`. Nos valdremos del
[unpacking](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/428956/qu%c3%a9-significa-variable-en-python/428961#428961) para obtener por un lado el índice y por el otro el item correspondiente.

Luego, si el condicional da verdadero, usamos la palabra reservada `break` para detener el bucle for. Podremos acceder entonces fuera del bucle for al valor que tiene la variable indice (que será del elemento cuyo titulo sea el buscado)

```
def eliminarCancion():

    eliminar = input('Ingrese el título de la canción: ')
    
    for indice, tema in enumerate(lista):
        if tema.titulo == eliminar:
            break

    del lista[indice]
```

**Nota** Este código asume que la canción escrita por el usuario existe. Si no encuentra la canción, borrará la ultima de la lista. Detectar si una canción existe o no es tarea para la casa ;)