# Problema de definición de objetos en python

Tags: python, mysql, modulos

Pues recientemente estaba siguiendo un curso de python con MYSQL, y en el curso estabamos creando una app para crear, eliminar bases de datos y crear y eliminar tablas de esas mismas bases, pero me dió un error al definir o llamar un objeto en uno de esos archivos, aclaro que estaba utilizando programación modular.
En el primer archivo llamado app.py simplemente se usa para pasar el directorio con el cual se hará la conexion a la base de datos y se llama a la funcion que se necesita usar, para eso importé en ese mismo archivo otro llamado db.py que está en una carpeta con ese mismo nombre, en ese archivo se hace la conexion, y se definen todos los metodos que se utilizarán, esos metodos estan en una clase llamada BaseDatos y despues en esa misma carpeta tengo otro archivo llamado tablas.py en el cual se pasa en directorios los valores de las columnas para crear la tabla, y al final se llama al objeto llamado base_dato que se definió en el archivo app.py y justo esa linea de la tabla me da error, que no se ah definido dicho objeto, aclaro que el archivo de la tabla lo importé en el archivo de la app.
Aquí les dejo los codigos de los 3 archivos

app.py:

```
import db.db as db
from db import tablas as tbl

base_datos = db.BaseDatos(**db.acceso_db)

base_datos.crear_tabla("pruebas", "proyecto", tbl.columnas)
```

db.py:

```
import mysql.connector
import os
import subprocess
import datetime

#Conexion a la base de datos

acceso_db = {"host" : "localhost",
             "user" : "root",
             "password" : "1024rw9210e19q2009"}

#RUTAS
ruta_raiz = os.path.dirname(__file__)
ruta_respaldo = os.path.join(ruta_raiz, "respaldo")

#Clase
class BaseDatos():
    #Metodo constructor
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.conector = mysql.connector.connect(**kwargs)
        self.cursor = self.conector.cursor()
        self.contrasena = kwargs["password"]

    #Funcion decoradora
    def reporte_bd(funcion_parametro):
        def interno(self, nombre_db):
            funcion_parametro(self, nombre_db)
            print("Estas son las bases de datos que hay en el servidor:")
            BaseDatos.mostrar_db(self)
        return interno

    #Consulta
    def consulta(self, sql):
        self.cursor.execute(sql)
        return self.cursor
    
    #Mostrar bases de datos
    def mostrar_db(self):
        self.cursor.execute("SHOW DATABASES")

        for db in self.cursor:
            print(db)
    
    #Eliminar bases de datos
    @reporte_bd
    def eliminar_db(self, nombre_db):
        try:
            self.cursor.execute(f"DROP DATABASE {nombre_db}")

            print(f"Se elimino la base de datos {nombre_db} correctamente")
        except:
            print(f"La base de datos '{nombre_db}' no ah sido encontrada")

    #Crear bases de datos
    @reporte_bd
    def crear_db(self, nombre_db):
        try:
            self.cursor.execute(f"CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {nombre_db}")

            print(f"La base de datos '{nombre_db}' se ah creado correctamente o ya había sido creada")
        
        except:
            print(f"Ocurrio un error al crear la base de datos '{nombre_db}'")
    
    #Copia de seguridad de bases de datos
    def copia_db(self, nombre_db):
        #Obtenemos fecha y hora actual (cap 32)
        fecha_actual = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S")

        with open(f'{ruta_respaldo}/{nombre_db}_{fecha_actual}.sql', 'w') as out:
            subprocess.Popen(f'"C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE/"mysqldump --user=root --password={self.contrasena} --databases {nombre_db}', shell=True, stdout=out)
    
    #Crear tablas (cap 34)
    def crear_tabla(self,nombre_db, nombre_tabla, columnas):
        columnas_string = ""

        for columna in columnas:
            columnas_string += f"{columna['name']} {columna['type']} ({columna['length']})"

            if columna['primary_key']:
                columnas_string += " PRIMARY KEY"
            
            if columna['auto_increment']:
                columnas_string += " AUTO_INCREMENT" 
            
            if columna['not_null']:
                columnas_string += " NOT NULL"
            
            columnas_string += ",\n"
        
        #Elimina al final del string el salto de línea y la coma    
        columnas_string = columnas_string[:-2]
        #Le indica que base de datos utilizar
        self.cursor.execute(f"USE {nombre_db}")
        #Se crea la tabla juntando la instrucción SQL con el string generado
        sql = f"CREATE TABLE {nombre_tabla} ({columnas_string});"
        #Se ejecuta la instrucción
        self.cursor.execute(sql)
        #Se confirman los cambios en la base de datos
        self.conector.commit()
        #Se cierra la conexión con el servidor
        self.conector.close()
```

tablas.py:

```
columnas = [
    {
        'name': 'id',
        'type': 'INT',
        'length': 10,
        'primary_key': True,
        'auto_increment': True,
        'not_null': True
    },
    {
        'name': 'nombre',
        'type': 'VARCHAR',
        'length': 32,
        'primary_key': False,
        'auto_increment': False,
        'not_null': True
    },
    {
        'name': 'apellidos',
        'type': 'VARCHAR',
        'length': 64,
        'primary_key': False,
        'auto_increment': False,
        'not_null': True
    },
    {
        'name': 'telefono',
        'type': 'VARCHAR',
        'length': 9,
        'primary_key': False,
        'auto_increment': False,
        'not_null': False
    },
    {
        'name': 'direccion',
        'type': 'VARCHAR',
        'length': 128,
        'primary_key': False,
        'auto_increment': False,
        'not_null': False
    }
]

base_datos.crear_tabla('base_datos_cualquiera', 'nombre_tabla', columnas) //En esta linea me da el error de que base_datos no se ah definido
```

Error en consola al ejecutar app.py:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\coloco\Documents\Cursos\Python\Día 26_32\app.py", line 2, in <module>       
    from db import tablas as tbl
  File "c:\Users\coloco\Documents\Cursos\Python\Día 26_32\db\tablas.py", line 44, in <module>
    base_datos.crear_tabla('base_datos_cualquiera', 'nombre_tabla', columnas) 
    ^^^^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'base_datos' is not defined
```

Se que a lo mejor sea un problema sencillo de resolver, eh pensado e intentado algunas soluciones pero no me sirven.
Espero y logran ayudarme.
Gracias

Comment: El problema es que en el archivo de tablas estás intentando usar una variable declarada en otro archivo, al que no tienes acceso allí. Cómo quieres que tablas.py sepa qué es `base_datos` si `base_datos` lo declaras en app.py?? Lo haces bien antes (por ejemplo para crear el objeto `base_datos`!), importando los archivos que necesitas usar, pero luego haces eso... no tiene mucho sentido. Que tú cuando programas uses los objetos creados en un orden específico no significa que esos objetos tengan acceso a los otros, solo tienes acceso a las cosas que importas en el propio archivo

Comment: Solución, mueve la línea que te da error al archivo en el que debería de estar, no puedes usar en tablas.py un objeto que no existe en ese archivo. O la solución que me gusta más a mi, crea una función en tablas.py que reciba un objeto del tipo que necesitas (BaseDatos) y lo usas para crear las tablas con él, pero el objeto has de proporcionárselo tu! El archivo no puede tener acceso a objetos que no existen en él

Comment: Gracias hermano, logré solucionarlo.

Answer (score -1):

Creería que el problema está en el uso incorrecto de los keyword arguments en la clase.

La nomenclatura `base_datos = db.BaseDatos(**db.acceso_db)` significa que el método constructor espera los argumentos tal cual ej: `def __init__(self, host, port, username, password, ...):`

Por el contrario la nomenclatura `base_datos = db.BaseDatos(db.acceso_db)` significa que quieres pasar el objeto `db.acceso_db` como un keyword argument object y puedes definir la clase como `def __init__(self, **kwargs):`

En resumen, es incongruente la forma en la que utilizas los ** con la forma en la que defines los parámetros en la clase **BaseDatos**. Como no existe un objeto con esos parámetros en su constructor se asume que no existe (pues no haces una referencia correcta a los argumentos).

Comment: No funciona de ese modo el asterisco en python. Mirá [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/428961/158880). La causa del error mencionada también es otra. Cuando Python dice "x is not defined" es que intenta buscar una variable y no la encuentra. No hay otro motivo. De hecho, parte de la filosofía de python es ser claro y no asumir. Viendo que dices "creo", te aclaro que la sección de respuestas no es para suposiciones. Antes de escribir una respuesta, asegurate que sea correcta. Finalmente, tus respuestas serán más acertadas si pruebas el código publicado. Aun así gracias por ayudar